# php reload page without posting data

Tags: php, javascript, html, refresh

I'm trying to refresh a page without sending POST from the previous time.

I've tried

```
window.open("postme.php?r=t", "_self");
```

Which appends a `?r=t` to the end but it doesn't appear to refresh the page as the page displays a number of files in a directory which hasn't change even though I have moved or deleted them.

Can you specify the URL in `window.location.reload();`?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got this to work...

window.location = "postme.php?r=t";

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid having refresh reporting data (for any reason, including the user clicking the reload button) then use the [POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 3):

Redirect the user to the same page after you're finished using their POST data.

```
$URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(!empty($_POST)){
    //magic

    header("location:$URI");
}
```

Now when you refresh, it won't have POST data to resubmit.

Answer (score 2):

Well.. late too I suppose, but then it could help someone. I used :

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

In replacement of location.reload(); this will refresh the page without prompting user to resend information.

Comment: Thanks Laurie. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
window.location.reload(true); //true sets request type to GET
```

Comment: that doesn't appear to work...still getting a warning about "Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've rpeviously transmitted"

Comment: Have you tried it without true, i.e. window.location.reload() ?

Comment: This is a bit misleading. `location.reload(true)` will force a refresh of the location without using the cache, but that depends entirely on the browser. There is no standard for this. It certainly will not turn a `POST` into a `GET`, that would be something like `location.reload(location.href)`.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is way late, and hope it applies: i had the same problem where when someone is confirming their inventory selection, it then emails the order [or subtracts from inventory database] then displays their order. then if they refresh, it resubmits the data. so i added a session_destroy(). but then when they refresh, there're lots of errors.

*SO* - i divided the code into [a]email the order/subtract from the inventory database, then [b]used a javascript "document.location.href='nextPage.php'" because i sometimes have problems using PHP's "location(nextpage.php)". anyway, it emails the info, then goes to the page that displays it. then one can refresh all they want and all that happens is it displays over and over.

hope that helps!