# window.location.href = window.location.href and JSLint

Tags: javascript, jslint

If using

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

to reload a page (without re-POSTing) is not bad practice, what should we make of JSLint's "*Weird assignment*" complaint?

**EDIT** `window.location.reload()` is not suitable when you don't want to POST the form data again. In some browsers it provokes the "Resend form data?" which is best avoided when not needed.

**UPDATE** I did some very brief testing and found:

- Chrome 12 and Safari 5.0.5 on Mac do not re-POST with `.reload()`
- FF 2.0, 3.6, 4.0, 5.0 on Mac present the user with the "resend form dialog" with `.reload()`, `.reload(true)`, and `.reload(false)`
- IE6, IE8(standards), IE8(IE7 mode,standards) in XP; and IE9 and IE10-tech-preview in Win7 behave the same as FF on Mac
- `window.location = window.location.href` works the same as `window.location.href = window.location.href` in all these browsers.

Here's [the test script](http://pastebin.com/vnJTsvKL).

Comment: Did you know there's an email list for jslint? You could ask questions like this there, too.

Comment: MDN Docs for [window.location.reload(forceGet);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#reload)

Comment: @ErikE: thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps this is something JSLint might like to tolerate when the `"browser"` option is set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

Comment: But doesn't `window.location.reload()` re-POST the form?

Comment: I think it will ask for retry in case of Post. I have edited my answer.

Comment: That's a naughty edit! 3 up-votes were for a different answer altogether. I'll need to check this in the browsers I'm required to support.

Comment: I added some browser compat research results on `window.location = window.location.href;` to the original quesiton.

Comment: Chrome: reloads the page with a GET
Firefox: re-executes the previous request, meaning if it was a POST, you'll get the nice popup asking you about whether to resend the data or not

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a weird assignment to assign something to itself. Sounds like more of a warning than a complaint.

I myself would prefer to use:

```
window.location.reload()
```

**Edit:** but that would repost the form now wouldn't it. Here's a post on SO about the same thing: [php reload page without posting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073593/php-reload-page-without-posting-data/1073732#1073732)

Comment: See my Q in the comment to ShankarSangoli

Comment: Post/redirect/get has its place but it's a server-side technique. If the client script decides to reload the page on, lets say, an ajax error, and should to use the page's current URL (with any query params it may have) but not re-POST, then `window.location.href = window.location.href;` is just the ticket.

Comment: I have an answer for you. Who cares what jslint says! :P

Answer (score 0):

It is a weird assignment, JSLint is right.  The issue is that setting the variable has the side effect of reloading the page.  I would code this as `window.location.href = window.location.href + '';` to avoid JSLint errors and put a comment explaining what it does.

Comment: No doubt it's a weird assignment. Unfortunately your suggestion does not help: *Problem at line 1 character 47: Expected 'String' and instead saw ''''.*

Comment: I could have sworn I checked it.  Another try: `window.location.href = window.location.href + String();`

Comment: That is OK with JSLint and will surely be equivalent to `window.location.href = window.location.href;`. But I think I prefer ShankarSangoli's `window.location = window.location.href;` which I think can allow without a comment.