# JavaScript to reload the page as GET request

Tags: javascript, refresh

I have a seemingly simple question, but can't find the answer. I have a webpage, which may have resulted from a POST request and may have an anchor (#) in the URL. I want to reload this page *as a GET request* in JavaScript. So it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascriptate), but I actually want to avoid the POST, not just the warning about it.

So, for example, if the page resulted from a POST request to "http://server/do/some?thing#" I want to reload the URL "http://server/do/some?thing" as a GET. If I try

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

that causes IE to try a POST. If I instead do:

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

this does nothing when the URL has an anchor. Do I really need to do string manipulation myself to get rid of the "#whatever" or is there an easier, "better" way to do this?

Comment: The "proper" way probably involves not doing a client-side page refresh.

Comment: Indeed, can you provide a little more context about the problem so that we know we're not about to reccomend you do something stupid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh the page with javascript and GET variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253754/refresh-the-page-with-javascript-and-get-variables)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
function reloadAsGet()
{
    var loc = window.location;
    window.location = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname + loc.search;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try the following:

```
location.replace(location.href)
```

Comment: This did not work for me in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
location=location.href
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: No-no-no, do it the right way: `location.assign(location.href);`