# Refresh the page with javascript and GET variables

Tags: javascript, get, refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var email = document.write(localStorage.getItem('email'));
var pass = document.write(localStorage.getItem('pass'));
var url = document.write(document.URL);
document.location.href = url+"?email="+email+"&pass="+pass;
</script>
```

But when I enter the page I left the url like this:
http://example.com/**undefined?email=undefined&pass=undefined**

Not happening ... Anyone know the problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, what's up with [`document.write(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) in here? You don't want to print out anything:

```
var email = localStorage.getItem('email');
```

But if you want to print out the values for testing:

```
var email = localStorage.getItem('email');
document.write(email);
```

(See also [`console.log(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log))

You should escape the parameters using [`encodeURIComponent(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
location.href = url + "?email=" + encodeURIComponent(email) +
                "&pass=" + encodeURIComponent(pass);
```

Also you should not use document.write anyhow. There are plenty more reasonable methods to change the content dynamically on you website.

You should not send a password using GET requests, as they will appear the browser, proxy and server logs. Use POST requests through invisible forms.