# Reload browser window after POST without prompting user to resend POST data

Tags: javascript

When a user visits my website there is a "Login" link on every page. Clicking this uses some JavaScript to show an overlay window where the user is prompted for their credentials. After entering these credentials an Ajax call is made to the web server to validate them; if they are valid, an authentication ticket cookie is sent back and the page is reloaded so that any content on the page that is specific to authenticated users or the (now) currently logged in user is displayed.

I am accomplishing the page reload via script using:

```
window.location.reload();
```

This works wonderfully for pages loaded via a GET request (the vast majority), but some pages use postback forms. So if a user goes to one of these pages, performs a postback, and then chooses to login, when the `window.location.reload()` script runs they are prompted with the dialog box asking if they want to resubmit the POST body.

[image: Resubmit POST body dialog box]

I thought to get around this I could just tell the browser to reload the page, so I tried:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

But the browser doesn't take any action with the above statement, I presume because it's thinking the new URL is the same as the old. If I change the above to:

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
```

It reloads the page, but I lose any querystring parameters.

My current workaround is sufficient, but not pretty - in short, I tack on a querystring parameter to the current `window.location.href` value and then assign that back to `window.location.href` by calling `reloadPage("justLoggedIn")`, where the `reloadPage` function is:

```
function reloadPage(querystringTackon) {
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;

    if (querystringTackon != null && querystringTackon.length > 0 && currentUrl.indexOf(querystringTackon) < 0) {
        if (currentUrl.indexOf("?") < 0)
            currentUrl += "?" + querystringTackon;
        else
            currentUrl += "&" + querystringTackon;
    }

    window.location.href = currentUrl;
}
```

This works, but it results in the URL being `www.example.com/SomeFolder/SomePage.aspx?justLoggedIn`, which seems tacky.

Is there a way in JavaScript to get it to do a GET reload and not prompt the user to resubmit the POST data? I need to make sure that any existing querystring parameters are not lost.

Comment: how about: `window.location.href = window.location.href + '&reload=1';` ?

Comment: @jnpcl: That, in essence, is my current workaround (see the `reloadPage` function I note above), but it feels tacky. I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Strange that `window.location.href = window.location.href` worked for me (reload the page) under Firefox and Chromium. Maybe try `window.location.replace(window.location.href)` (that additionally makes the page reload transparent to the user history) ...

Answer (score 54):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Don't ask my why it works..but it does :).
Just the way the js engine interprets the logic I suppose.

Comment: Does not work for GET either, at least on Firefox this does nothing.

Comment: Funny how this apparently doesn't do what it's supposed to do, yet people visiting this page keep up voting it... Maybe people come to this page attempting to do the *opposite* of what the OP intended?  (e.g. "reload" the page and omit POST parameters)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It does work across browsers. However I have to state that it only works on all browsers if after form is submitted it doesn't load the same page. @rinogo

Comment: This is not a good answer since, the post data is just not sent.

Answer (score 9):

What you probably need to do is redirect the user after the POST / Form Handler script has been ran.

In PHP this is done like so...

```
<?php
// ... Handle $_POST data, maybe insert it into a database.
// Ok, $_POST data has been handled, redirect the user
header('Location:success.php');
die();
?>
```

... this *should* allow you to refresh the page without getting that "Send Data Again" warning.

You can even redirect to the same page (if that's what you're posting to) as the POST variables will not be sent in the headers (and thus not be there to re-POST on refresh)

Comment: The problem is the application is an ASP.NET Web Forms app, so there are a lot of postbacks and I can't modify this ingrained ASP.NET functionality.

Comment: That modification to the .NET functionality might warrant another question. I guess what I'm trying to say is that the "solution" to this problem would be attack the cause (Which is not redirecting the user after post) -- I wish I knew more about .NET to help you out there =/

Answer (score 7):

This works too:

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search
```

Comment: Maybe, but this works and is better than a prior answer suggesting that  "window.location.href = window.location.href;" would work while it doesn't.

Comment: This does not send the post values

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

`window.location = window.location.pathname;`

Tested on

- Chrome 44.0.2403
- IE edge
- Firefox 39.0

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
RefreshForm.submit();
```

instead of

```
document.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can add a unique id to your submit button and then call

`$("my_button_id").click()`

Comment: this is the best solution.  You can control exactly what data is sent this way.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved also with POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern.
Which is more elegant:
[How do I reload a page without a POSTDATA warning in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript/570069#570069)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you.

Here's what I did (dynamically generated GET form with action set to location.href, hidden input with fresh value), and it seems to work in all browsers:

```
var elForm=document.createElement("form");
elForm.setAttribute("method", "get");
elForm.setAttribute("action", window.location.href);

var elInputHidden=document.createElement("input");
elInputHidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
elInputHidden.setAttribute("name", "r");
elInputHidden.setAttribute("value", new Date().getTime());
elForm.appendChild(elInputHidden);

if(window.location.href.indexOf("?")>=0)
{
    var _arrNameValue;
    var strRequestVars=window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("?")+1);
    var _arrRequestVariablePairs=strRequestVars.split("&");
    for(var i=0; i<_arrRequestVariablePairs.length; i++)
    {
        _arrNameValue=_arrRequestVariablePairs[i].split("=");

        elInputHidden=document.createElement("input");
        elInputHidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        elInputHidden.setAttribute("name", decodeURIComponent(_arrNameValue.shift()));
        elInputHidden.setAttribute("value", decodeURIComponent(_arrNameValue.join("=")));
        elForm.appendChild(elInputHidden);
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(elForm);
elForm.submit();
```

Comment: Any idea how to do something like this but still allow for hashes on the URL to be preserved?

Comment: @jamauss Have you tried setting the hash on the action URL using the code above?

Comment: @jamauss The real question is: why didn't you?

Comment: I didn't think hashes were allowed on form action URLs. I tried it now and the problem I have is that it ends up URL encoded. So instead of submitting a form to mysite/thread?thread=3#17 is submits to mysite/thread?thread=3%2317 and so the thread querystring value ends up being 3%2317 instead of 3.

Comment: Maybe you can work around it by setting a query parameter "_fragment", and then do a second reload by setting location.href.

Comment: So I was able to get it so that the form action URL was like mysite/thread?#17 with a hidden input named "thread" with a value of "3" and the page would not refresh when the form.submit() was called. Not sure why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33437/discussion-between-jamauss-and-tiberiu-ionu-stan)

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post, but I do have a better solution.  Create a form containing all of your post values as hidden fields and give the form a name such as:

```
<form name="RefreshForm" method="post" action="http://yoursite/yourscript">
    <input type="hidden" name="postVariable" value="PostData">
</form>
```

Then all you need to do in your `setTimeout` is `RefreshForm.submit();`

Cheers!

Comment: This will attempt to resend all the post information. Why would you copy post data and resend? What you actually want to do is to reload the page without a post

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create an empty form, method=get, and submitting it.

```
<form id='reloader' method='get' action="enter url here"> </form>
<script>
// to reload the page, try
document.getElementById('reloader').submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have hashes '#' in your URL, all the solutions here do not work. This is the only solution that worked for me.

```
var hrefa = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
var hrefb = window.location.href.split("#")[2];
window.location.href  = window.location.pathname +  window.location.search + '&x=x#' + hrefa + '#' + hrefb;
```

The URL has to be different for it to reload if you have a hash. The &x=x does that here. Just substitute this for something you can ignore. THis is abit of a hack, unable to find a better solution..

Tested in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

When we want to refresh the parent page from the child page without any prompt.

Here is the code:

window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location;

This simply refreshes the parent page without any prompt.

Answer (score 0):

To reload opener window with all parameters (not all be sent with window.location.href method and method with form.submit() is maybe one step to late) i prefer to use window.history method.

```
window.opener.history.go(0);
```

Comment: Note: If the page was opened in a new window, this will reload the previous window, not the one you're on. At least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [HTML prompt to unload](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#prompt-to-unload-a-document) mechanism, by specifying no unload handler:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
window.location.replace(URL);
```

[See the notes section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) of the `WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
<button onclick="window.location.href=window.location.href; return false;">Continue</button>
```

The reason it doesn't work without the `return false;` is that the button click would trigger a form submit. With an explicit return false on it, it doesn't do the form submit and just does the reload of the same page that was a result of a previous POST to that page.