# Pull Sharepoint out of infinite loop

Tags: loops, post, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

...This one was my fault..

I have a SharePoint 2013 calendar page which I want to auto refresh.  The refresh was working but I kept getting the retry/cancel message if the view was adjusted in any way.  I found a solution suggestion of `window.location.href = window.location.href;`

From this question:[Reload browser window after POST without prompting user to resend POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869721/reload-browser-window-after-post-without-prompting-user-to-resend-post-data)

> Unfortunately, I put that logic outside of my loop as well which now has the page indefinitely refreshing..
>   With the constant refresh I cannot edit / discard the check out to remove the looping logic

I logged in as a different user thinking I could override the checkout, but the option is not available to override and i'm still looping.

> I am hoping for a URL command which will either bring up the edit page option or somehow discard the checkout

Worst case I can delete and recreate the page, its still in test but I would rather not. (I am able to get into site settings and site content, just can't edit the page)

Answer (score 0):

I opened the page is SharePoint Designer and edited the .aspx in Advanced mode, found my function and removed the loop