# html refresh the page without sending form data again besides ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form sending data via post to the page of itself. I want to refresh the page without sending form data again just like you go to the page initially.As far as I know I can use ajax to do so, but it is quite complicated. And, I am looking for simpler method to do so. I have searched overriding refresh but it is not possible. So, do you have any methods refreshing the page without sending form data again besides ajax?

my code of abc.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "<form action='abc.php' method='post'>";
if(isset($_POST["edit_u_name"])){
  echo "<br><br>name: <input type='text' name='user_name' maxlength='20' value='" .  $u_name . "'>  <input type='submit' name='confirm_u_name' value='confirm'><input type='submit' name='cancel_u_name' value='cancel'>";
}
else    
  echo "<br><br>name: ". $u_name. " <input type='submit' name='edit_u_name' value='edit'>";     

echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press the edit button and then refresh, I want go to the page just like directly going to the page initially with sending data of edit button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload browser window after POST without prompting user to resend POST data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869721/reload-browser-window-after-post-without-prompting-user-to-resend-post-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["u_name"])){
        $u_name = $_POST["u_name"];
    } else {
        $u_name = '';
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action='abc.php' method='post'>
        <span id="in" style="display: none">
            <br>
            <br>name: <input type='text' name='u_name' maxlength='20' value='<?php echo $u_name; ?>'>
            <input type='submit' name='confirm_u_name' value='confirm'>
            <input type='reset' name='cancel_u_name' value='cancel'>
        </span>
        <span id="ed">
            <br>
            <br>name: <?php echo ($u_name =='')?'--':$u_name; ?><input type='button' value="Edit" 
                onclick="document.getElementById('ed').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('in').style.display = 'block';">
        </span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will it also not send the data when I press the submit button?

Comment: Pressing submit button will always send form data to server unless you disable the button after the data is submitted once.

Comment: Would you mind that you give an example so that I can test it whether it does work or not?

Comment: My code is uploaded. I don't know where to put location.reload(true). I have tried like    <body onload location.reload(true)> and it will refresh repeatedly and unstoppably.

Comment: Yes, it works. The way of this method is hide-and-show I will call it. Thank you.