# Refresh page using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, post

I send a post request to the server, which inturn returns a JSP. Now if i use the refresh button of the browser, i get a confirmation to resubmit the data, and then the page reloads successfully.

However, when i try to refresh the page using javascript, i dont get any confirmation box, and the reload also doesnt work. Ive tried all methods of reload like :

- location.reload()
- window.location.reload()
- window.location.href = window.location.href
- history.go(0);

I think the problem is that its sending a get request when i try to refresh using javascript, and it is not able to find the necessary paramaters.

This problems occurs only in chrome... it works in Firefox and IE!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The `reload` method may use the cache to reload the page. Specify the force parameter to make it get the page from the server:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: force parameter is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

```
parent.window.location.reload(true);
```

worked on chrome for me ... finally

explanation: of parent.window

A reference to the parent of the current window or subframe.

If a window does not have a parent, its parent property is a reference to itself.

When a window is loaded in an , , or , its parent is the window with the element embedding the window.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to call the same URL with some additional value.

This is regular reloading script, this works fine on IE & FF but not on Chrome & Safari.

```
window.location = location.href;
```

To make reload work on all browser types use:

```
window.location = location.href + '?session=' + sMath.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
```

Tested on IE, FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Adding a random key to the page link should do the trick. The point is that browser will not reload until page link is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the possible solutions found (ajax calls, various snippets) but the only thing worked for me was disabling the network cache from chrome see here [Why isn't Google Chrome reloading my scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045424/why-isnt-google-chrome-reloading-my-scripts)
I don't think it is a solution for production but while developing can spare you some time from searching. The problem seems to be with chrome's cache and even setting

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

does not clear the cache while reloading. On FF works fine.

Answer (score -1):

In order to "refresh" the page via a post request, you need to submit a form. You can use any form already on the page, or create one programmatically.

```
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
myForm.action = "/my/url.jsp"; // Or use window.location, or something else.
myForm.method = "POST";
document.body.appendChild(myForm); // Needs to be in the DOM. Is not visible.
myForm.submit();
```

Comment: The problem is this:
i submit a form on page 1. It takes me to page 2. now when im on page 2, if i click on browser's reload, then page 2 refreshes successfully (after getting a confirmation). However, if i put a this:
`<a href="javascript:history.go(0);">Reload</a>`
on page 2, and if i click on it, then i cant reload the page, since it doesnt send the necessary params of page1 form. 
My question is that is it possible to implement the same functionality of browser's reload button?