# Is it a preferred way to reuse a url with different http methods?

Tags: rest, http-method

For example, when making a payment with credit-card we `POST` to url `/paymybill-cc`. And we want to avoid reposting when the user refresh the page. In this case, is it a preferred way to redirect to the same url with `GET` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the `POST` happens to a url specifying what you want to create, like in your case, but the `GET` should happen to a url like `/paymybill-cc/:id` to get a specific one.

If I were allowed to `GET /paymybill-cc` I would expect it to return all payments, maybe with a default limit, but a lot of them.

If the user reloads the page that contains `POST` data then he will be prompted about resubmitting his data to the server. See [How do I reload a page without a POSTDATA warning in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript) for a bit more details on that.