# Removing Alert while refreshing page

Tags: jsf, post-redirect-get

I am trying to refresh an xhtml page in a JSF application using the following command.

```
onclick="window.location.reload( true );"
```

In that I am getting an alert 
"requested page is already submitted..with Retry and Cancel buttons".

How to remove this warning.

Answer (score 0):

That warning is shown by the client browser, you cannot remove it. What you can do is apply the Post Redirect Get Pattern.

- [Redirect After Post](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)
- [BalusC's solution](http://balusc.blogspot.co.at/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html)
- [Post Redirect Get on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

The popup you get means that some data was sent to the server with POST and the server processed the data. If you reload the page (F5) the data will be sent to the server **again** which could lead to unexpected results.

See similar questions:

- [How do I reload a page without a POSTDATA warning in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript)
- and even more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-redirect-get