# How to refresh a page in JavaScript without POSTing?

Tags: javascript, browser

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5404839/65387) already, but the top answers all suggest `window.location.reload`. I've just discovered that this will actually do a `POST` if your page was loaded with a POST.

I reckon I could do `window.location.href=window.location.href` but that won't work if there's a hashtag in the URL I'm told.

So how can I get the browser to perform a GET on the current page, including query params (with or without the hash)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reload a page without a POSTDATA warning in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function refresh() {
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
};
```

You don't need the `origin` (it doesn't work in old IE anyway). You should add `.search` if you want to keep the query params. Don't add `.hash` because it won't refresh if there is one.

Comment: Perfect answer! Works very fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can manually construct your URL:

```
window.location.href=window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
```

Comment: The `+ window.location.hash` causes it to *not* navigate when there is a hash. Without it it works fine though. Thank you!