# How to disable alert on parent page on refresh from Popup in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

From a pop up  JSP page, on close I am refreshing the parent page.

POPUP page is created by:

```
top.f_dialogOpen(url, 'MYPOPUPPAGE','width=1200px, height=470px');
```

JS to close the popup and refresh the parent page:

```
function closePopUp()
{
    top.frames.location.reload(false);
    top.f_dialogClose();
}
```

This refreshes the parent page but before refreshing following JS alert appears:

[image]

Can I disable this alert? I dnt want this alert to appear as I refresh the parent page

Comment: This previous question might help answer your question: [How do I reload a page without a POSTDATA warning in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Roberto, based on your recommended link, 
Just changing window.location in JavaScript is dangerous because the user could still hit the back button and resubmit the post, which could have unexpected results (such as a duplicate purchase). PRG is a much better solution