# Reload current page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[Alert Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whDBH.png)I want to reload the current page using `history.go(0). This isn't working in IE, and I'm getting a pop up.

I have tried with `location.reload()`, and Firefox is having an issue, getting same popup.

`window.location.href = window.location.href & window.location.reload(true)` goes to the main login page and doesn't save my dropdown.

How can I correctly reload the current page?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure to check out the [how to ask page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Can you show the error message in the popup? It's not clear what the specific problem is.

Comment: To display the webpage again, the web browser need to resend the information you've previously submitted.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570015/how-do-i-reload-a-page-without-a-postdata-warning-in-javascript) might answer your question.

Comment: when I use that it is not loading the current page, it going to main login page :(

Comment: Did you just submitted form and now want to reload page?

Comment: My page will reload every 1 minute